# How to extract word which has only numbers separated by 'dot'

Tags: linux, text-processing, pattern-matching

From below lines

```
abcd efgh ijhk lmn opqrs 9.0.8.2c tuv wxyz
abcd efgh ijhk lmn opqrs 8.1.3.9b
```

How to extract only

```
9.0.8.2c
8.1.3.9b
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if your sample had more examples of things you don't want it to match (like what about `foo1.2`, `foo-1.2`, `1.2-3`). How do you define _word_? How do you define _number_? `9c` being a _number_ implies numbers here are hexadecimal numbers. Is that right?

Comment: Why isn't `abcd` to be matched? That's an hexadecimal number as well. Is that because you need those _words_ to contain at least two numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
grep -oE "(\w*[.]\w*)*" file
9.0.8.2c
8.1.3.9b
```

Comment: Perhaps end with `+` instead of `*`, to avoid matching the empty string?  The output will be the same, but the `*` form will report "success" even on files containing no such words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 grep -E -o '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][^[:space:]]+' file
```

- `-E` Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
- `-o` Print only the matched parts of a matching line
- `[^[:space:]]+` until white space

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, updated for `dot`, ...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  i ment `\w+` as untile white space, since `\w` followed by `+`.... correct me if im wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If by *word*, you mean sequence of non-whitespace characters, and by *number*, you mean hexadecimal (without sign or leading `0x`, so sequence of 0123456789abcdefABCDEF characters), and that you need at least two of those numbers per word (otherwise `abcd` would be matched as well), with GNU `grep` you can do:

```
grep -Pio '(?<!\S)[0-9a-f]+(\.[0-9a-f]+)+(?!\S)'
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'for (/\S+/g) {print if /^[\da-f]+(\.[\da-f]+)+$/}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are inside a file, with pcre grep:

```
 $ grep -P '(([0-9a-f]+)\.)(?1)+(?2)' file
 9.0.8.2c
 8.1.3.9b
```

Or with perl:

```
 perl -lne '/((([\da-f]+)\.)(?2)+(?3))/;print $1' file
```